# SPI Daisy-chain with paralleled DIN

Tags: stm32, spi, dac, hal-library

I'm trying to use daisy-chaining feature on three MAX5318 DAC's.

[image]

However, I'm not sure how to do it properly. Do I need to turn CS low, then write 9 byte to SPI DIN, then double-trigger LDAC? Or to double-toggle LDAC after each 3-byte transmission?

Tried all variants, both seems to don't work. Googling internet, I find daisy-chaining with paralleled CS, not DIN, so I can't figure out how to use paralleled DIN version of daisy-chaining.

[image]

Comment: The first pic isn't what I'd call daisy chain, to me daisy chain is slave MISO -> next slave's MOSI like in pic 2. And you'll tie all slaves /CS to /SS or ground. In this case I don't see how daisy chain makes sense, since you don't seem to return the DOUT to the MCU MISO. Why are you using daisy chain if you aren't interested in reading the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Do I need to turn CS low, then write 9 byte to SPI DIN, then
> double-trigger LDAC? Or to double-toggle LDAC after each 3-byte
> transmission?*

[image]

You activate LDAC after you have written the serial data into all three DACs and, you should ideally double check that what comes back on MISO is the data you wrote to each DAC. That gives you some confidence about things. You can activate LDAC straight after DAC3 data is seen on MISO.